# Ray optics combination of lenses

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

If there are two thin lenses of any type, separated by some distance say, $8\; cm$, a question is asking for effective focal length of the two lenses. Can I assume that in between the two given lenses there are many other lenses made of air and since they are made of air their focal length will be infinity and then we can apply the formula $\frac{1}{f_{eq}} = \frac{1}{f_1}+\frac{1}{f_2}$? This is not working why?

Comment: 1/infinity = 0 .

Comment: I know that @An_Elephant XD, I can understand it does not make any sense mathematically to add zero but is this theoretically wrong? I meant about the part where I assume there are many lenses made of air in between them.

Comment: You can add zero as many times as you like. It doesn't change the result. If you want to learn how to do this "right", then you will find that lens systems can be described with matrices. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a single lens with focal length $f_1$, and a second lens with focal length $f_2=\infty$. If we calculate the effective focal length of the combined system using the lens maker formula, we obtain $f_{eff} = f_1$, because your formula yields $\frac{1}{f_{eff}} =  \frac{1}{f_{1}} + \frac{1}{f_{2}} = \frac{1}{f_{1}}$. Therefore, the second lens does not do anything.

If you imagine that the two lenses are placed a distance $d$ apart from each another, we could apply the formula
$\frac{1}{f_{eff}} =  \frac{1}{f_{1}} + \frac{1}{f_{2}} - \frac{d}{f_1 f_2}$. Again, we find $f_{eff} = f_1$ and the second lens does nothing. So I would say that these formulas are working!